# enrichActivities in Laravel and getstream example

Tags: getstream-io

What  `enrichActivities`  (Laravel 5) do in `$activities = $enricher->enrichActivities($activities);`?

If it compare the activities from `getstream` and local database, can't be handle all this thing in `getstream` instead of enriching it with local database?

Comment: can you add the reason you want to skip the enrichment step?

Comment: I dont want to store activity on my db. i want to store activity on getstream..I did not understand why enrichment is require

Comment: any suggestion please

Comment: using the enrichment is necessary to store references to your data in feeds (eg. users, images, posts, comments). Perhaps you should close this question and open a new one with more information about the model layer of your app